# Awk, tail, sed or others - which one faster for big files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have scripts for big log files. I can check all line and do something with `tail` and `awk`.

Tail:

```
tail -n +$startline $LOG
```

Awk:

```
awk 'NR>='"$startline"' {print}' $LOG
```

And checking time, tail working 6 mins 39 seconds, awk working 6 mins 42 seconds. So two commands do same thing / same time.

I don't know how to do with sed. Sed can be faster than tail and awk? Or maybe other commands.

---

Second question, I use `$startline` and every time continue remains from the last line. For example:

I use script line this:

```
10:00AM -> ./script -> $startline=1 and do something -> write line number to save file(for ex. 25),
10:05AM -> ./script -> $startline=26(read save file +1) and do something -> write line number save file(55),
10:10AM -> ./script -> $startline=56(read save file +1) and do something ....
```

But when script is running, checking all lines and when see `$startline`, doing something. And it's a little slow because of huge files.

Any suggestions for it be faster?

Script example:

```
lastline=$(tail -1 "line.save")
startline=$(($lastline + 1))
tail -n +$startline $LOG | while read -r
do
....
done
linecount=$(wc -l "$LOG" | awk '{print $1}')
echo $linecount >> line.save
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean with your second question. Could you share what does `script` contain?

Comment: Well one thing you can initially do is to use `linecount=$(wc -l <"$LOG")` to get the line number. With `<` you avoid getting the file name, so you directly have the number with no further processing needed. Regarding the rest of the script, I don't see much you can do. Maybe `tail -f` and keep processing the input?

Comment: Thanks, actually I need faster way for startline. For example if log have 10.000.000 lines, and need to start 9.000.000, awk and tail read line numbers and going 9.000.000. I need to do go directly 9.000.000. line. Tail and awk losing time reading the number of lines.

Comment: As far as I know, the system has no way to access to a specific line other than counting line by line until the one you need is found. I see the problem is in the `$LOG` file, so if you really want to process lines as they come, I again suggest you to work with the output of `tail -f`. This will "keep an eye" on the file by keeping it open and sees what is being written on every moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tail` and `head` are tools especially created for this purposes, so the intuitive idea is that their are quite optimized for it. On the other hand, `awk` and `sed` can perfectly do it because they are like a [Swiss Army knife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Army_knife), but this is not supposed to be its best "skill" over the multiple others that they have.

In [Efficient way to print lines from a massive file using awk, sed, or something else?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94318/40596) there is a nice comparison on methods and `head` / `tail` is seen as the best approach.

Hence, I would go for `tail` + `head`.

---

Note also that if it is not only the last lines, but a set of them within the text, in `awk` (or in `sed`) you have the option to `exit` after the last line you wanted. This way, you avoid the script to run the file until the last line.

So this:

```
awk '{if (NR>=10 && NR<20) print} NR==20 {print; exit}'
```

is faster than

```
awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=20'
```

If your input happens to contain more than 20 lines.

---

Regarding your expression:

```
awk 'NR>='"$startline"' {print}' $LOG
```

note that it is more straight forward to write:

```
awk -v start="$startline" 'NR>=start' $LOG
```

there is no need to say `print` because it is implicit.

Comment: Print NR>= to end of file, not 10-20. I think don't need to do for this?

Comment: You mean in your case you just want to print up to the end of the file, right? For this yes, `exit` does not make sense because it would happen on the last line. Editing it.